Network and local search showing "zero byte" files that don't exist, even using `mdfind`
It seems like a stale cache somewhere (local or remote or both) but I don't know where and need help understanding how to remove these references to deleted files.
After doing a command+f to search a network volume Finder shows files that previously existed but presently don't exist on that volume. They are shown as being "zero bytes" except for one which shows a non-zero byte size.
Running ls -la on that volume on that machine shows that these files do not exist.
Running the find command on that volume doesn't show they exist.
Control clicking on the zero byte file and selecting Open shows a window with this text:

The alias “filename” can’t be opened because the original item can’t
be found.

clicking on "Delete Alias" does nothing.
Running mdfind kMDItemKind="Alias"  doesn't show this file.
Running mdfind  kMDItemPhysicalSize="0" doesn't show this file.
Running mdfind  kMDItemDisplayName="filename" doesn't show this file.
Running mdls <"path to file"> says the file that is listed in Finder does not exist... "could not find /path/to/file"
Dragging this file from the Finder Search Results window into Terminal doesn't add its path to Terminal.
This is a shared volume via smb.
Attempts to troubleshoot:

I unmounted the volumes and remounted them thinking this might update the file directories.
I restarted the computer.
I cleared the user cache at ~/Library/Cache and restarted.
I ran Disk Utility First Aid


The solution, which was the last thing I expected, was to rebuild the Spotlight index. The last thing I expected because those files weren't found when searching the Spotlight index!

Spotlight was and always will be asynchronous. Sometimes it will find ghosts, sometimes it will not find a file created 2 minutes sooner.[↵]
The best answer is:
to remember when you need to find a file reliably, despite all the extended attributes it may have, despite all the mds which are running on your whole disk space, the only reliable tool is find.
Spotlight is just a simple tool to help beginners.
